# Can't load ES6 module with require

Tags: ecmascript-6, browserify, es6-module-loader

I'm using gulp + browserify to compile an es6 to es5 and then trying to `require` that in another module (neither of these work):

```
Main = require('mylibrary/dist/main').Main
Main2 = require('mylibrary/dist/main')
```

Also tried to to `export default class Main` and tried `class Main` then `export default new Main`

I'm sure this is something simple that I'm missing?

es6 class:

```
export class Main {
  constructor(){
    console.log('Main!');
  }

  test(){
    console.log('test');
  }
}
```

output (abbreviated):

```
var Main = exports.Main = function () {
  function Main() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Main);

    console.log('Main!');
  }

  _createClass(Main, [{
    key: 'test',
    value: function test() {
      console.log('test');
    }
  }]);

  return Main;
}();
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require("vinyl-source-stream");
var babelify = require("babelify");

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    return browserify({
        entries: ['src/main.js'],
        debug: true
    })
  .transform(babelify, {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
    .bundle()
  .on("error", function (err) { console.log("Error : " + err.message); })
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('src/*.js', ['browserify']);
    gulp.watch('src/*.jsx', ['browserify']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch','browserify']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Browserify builds a file meant to be run in a browser, not one that is meant to work with `require`. You want to use Browserify's [`standalone`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) option via

```
return browserify({
    entries: ['src/main.js'],
    debug: true,
    standalone: 'someName',
})
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have to read up more details on this.  So after adding standalone: true I got the following error: `node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-pack/node_modules/umd/index.js:55
  var names = name.split('.')
                   ^

TypeError: name.split is not a function`

Comment: Sorry, I think I had it wrong, it's not `true`, it should be a string.